# How to modify an XML file embedded in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am developing an application in C# that interacts with `DLL` assemblies exchanging values, since the application can read and write in the `DLL` file.

Each `DLL` file is a class library project, since they are plugins that extend the functionality of my application; nevertheless, I need that each `DLL` can store certain parameters that my application can read and modify freely and that when modified, these parameters keep their value permanently.

Each `DLL` file has an embedded `DLL` file to store these parameters (obviously I can not load the `XML` by its path as it is inside a `DLL`), however, I can not change the values ​​of the nodes in the `XML` file.

Having said that, I have the following class in the `DLL` assembly:

```
public class AssemblyData
{
   private Assembly assembly;
   private XmlDocument xmldocument;
   private Stream stream;

   public AssemblyData()
   {
      this.assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      this.xmldocument = new XmlDocument();
      string classNamespace = typeof(AssemblyData).Namespace;
      this.stream = this.assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{classNamespace}.Settings.xml");
      this.xmldocument.Load(this.stream);
   }

   public string Test
   {
      get => this.xmldocument.SelectSingleNode("Settings/Test").InnerText;
      set
      {
         this.xmldocument.SelectSingleNode("Settings/Test").InnerText = value;
         this.SaveXml();
      }
   }

   public void SaveXml()
   {
      this.xmldocument.Save(this.stream);
   }
}
```

However, the value of the `Test` node never changes. What is this about?

Comment: _"I need that each DLL can store certain parameters that my application can read and modify freely and that when modified, these parameters keep their value permanently"_ - don't use embedded files, then, because you can't change those.

Comment: @stuartd Then should I import the XML by its file path?

Comment: “since the application can read and write in the DLL file”. Not if a non-administrator is running the app it can't. And even if one is, when that administrator repairs your application all your changes get deleted. So don't do that. If you need to persist changes, copy the files [somewhere all users have write access to and that doesn't get deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Environment_GetFolderPath_System_Environment_SpecialFolder_) and make all your changes there.

Comment: It looks like the xml file is a configuration file and somebody decided not to have users modify the configuration file directly but to use the dll.  Probably the xml file is read only (except of admins) and the dll is providing a method for non admins to change the file.  Probably the dll has run as admin execution privileges to modify the xml.